# String.replace() is not working

Tags: java, string, replace

What I have is a string array that I am creating from a .csv file I am reading. I then want to parse the values I'm going to use for the ' character and replace it with a \' because I am outputting this to a javascript file.

Here's the code I'm using for that:

```
while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] line = thisLine.split("\t");                       
            if(line[4].indexOf("'") > -1){
                System.out.println(line[4]);
                line[4] = line[4].replace("'", "\'");
                System.out.println(line[4]);
            }               
            brand.add(line[4]);         
}
```

However this is not working. I am getting the same string back after I do the replace.

Is this because of some issue with the string array?

I appreciate any assistance in this matter.

Comment: Java escapes the backslash char too. Use `"\\'"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this:

```
line[4] = line[4].replace("'", "\\'");
```

The backslash must be "escaped".

In case of `line[4] = line[4].replace("'", "\'");` the part `\'` is converted to just `'`

Comment: You are not dumb. Never call yourself such way, the thoughts are material. We all have a field to study any time.

Answer (score 6):

You're falling foul of the fact that `"'"` is the same as `"\'"`. They're the same string (a single character, just an apostrophe) - the escaping is there to allow a *character* literal of `'\''`.

You want:

```
line[4] = line[4].replace("'", "\\'");
```

So now you're escaping the backslash, instead of the apostrophe. So you're replacing apostrophe with backslash-then-apostrophe, which is what you wanted.

See [JLS section 3.10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) for details of escaping in character and string literals.

Answer (score 1):

you should add back slash \ something like this

```
line[4] = line[4].replace("'", "\\'");
```

because one  left slash \ is escape character

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like it is an escape issue. Try \\ to replace a single back slash.